# Difference between Sliding Window technique and Scanning Window technique in image searching

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

To search through images, sometimes the Sliding Window technique is used and sometimes the Scanning Window technique. What is the different between these two techniques?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by scanning vs. sliding?

Comment: I don't know it exactly. I found these two words while reading some research papers. I have a suggestion that scanning window technique uses exhaustive search through the image and other one not. But have no clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

The term that is more widely used is the sliding window. Many object detection schemes use a sliding window approach, where the window is processed by some detector (say, SVM). Density estimation by Parzen windows is also a sliding window approach, if the density is required for every pixel.

I'm guessing that the distinction between the two may be the ability to process the current window based on the partial overlap with the 'previous' window. If your operator is linear, there are many efficient ways that can utilize the overlap (e.g. incremental increment/decrement operations, or FFT+convolution). Perhaps scanning is defined as a process that covers the image, but doesn't or cannot utilize the overlap between windows.